# How should an 'ANY' IPv4/IPv6 address behave?

Tags: c++

This is more of a semantics than technical question.

Let's have a class `IpAddress`. Among other ways of construction, it can also be default-constructed - in that case it does not have a version and acts as an 'ANY' address for both IPv4 and IPv6. However, how should it behave in case of for example `toString()`, should it return `"0.0.0.0 / ::"`?

Comment: That'd work, but if you want it to be an invalid address I would display something more informative, like `NOT_SET` or something.

Comment: @KEYSER It isn't invalid, and he didn't say anything to suggest the contrary.